# Listen to Swf Panel close

Tags: actionscript-3, air, jsfl

I'm working on a project for flash pro cs and I would like to know when a Flash Pro user closes an SWF panel.
The panel needs to know before it closes and perform a function before that.

Is there a way to do this?

I know this is possible in Air but that doesn't work as a flash pro panel.

Just to clear clarify, I mean a swf panel added to flash Professional as an extension, through the WindowSWF library under "AppData\Local\Adobe\Flash CS6\en_US\Configuration".

basically, if there is no way to do it via JSFL calls, I would need to find a way to listen to the close event from within the swf itself.

Any ideas? Hacks are more then welcome...

Comment: what do you mean by swf panel?

Comment: you can try closing event, but it wont work in all browsers.

Comment: I need to catch the event either from a JSFL call/listener as it will run inside flash professional CS3-5. not in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps listen for the addedToStage and removedFromStage events in the child SWF and act accordingly?

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#event:addedToStage

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#event:removedFromStage

Comment: Tried that, no go. When an swf Panel, or a flash player window are closed, non of these events are closed. I think the OS flushes its memory so there really isn't anything internal in flash that can do it. it's needs to be an event caught by the OS somehow like air does.